# Sum of two functions is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, does that imply each of them is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, fourier-transform, fractional-sobolev-spaces

> Let $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a measurable function such that $\Delta u - (-\Delta)^{\lambda} u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Does that imply each of $\Delta u$ and $(-\Delta)^{\lambda} u$ is  in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Here $(-\Delta)^{\lambda}$ denotes the fractional laplacian.

I considered Fourier transform,  $\mathcal{F}({\Delta u - (-\Delta)^{\lambda} u})= -|\xi|^2\hat u(\xi)-|\xi|^{2\lambda} \hat u(\xi)$ and we know $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ implies $\hat u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I'm not sure how to conclude using these informations.

Comment: Where do you need further help?  Also, note that your expression for the Fourier transform has a sign error.

Comment: I don't know how to conclude using the information I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbR}{\mathbb{R}}$Certainly, it is enough to prove that $(-\Delta)^\lambda u$ is in $L^2(\bbR^n)$.  Moreover, since the Fourier transform and its inverse are bounded on $L^2$, it suffices to prove that $|\xi|^{2\lambda}\hat{u} \in L^2$.

No this end, notice that 
$$|\xi|^{2\lambda} \hat{u} = \left\{\frac{|\xi|^{2\lambda}}{|\xi|^2 + |\xi|^{2\lambda}}\right\}\left(|\xi|^2 + |\xi|^{2\lambda}\right) \hat{u}.$$
The term in curly braces is in $L^\infty$, while the second term is in $L^2$ by assumption, so we can apply Holder's inequaltiy to conclude that $(-\Delta)^\lambda u \in L^2$.

Comment: I think we don't need Holder's inequality!